# ON/OFF the identity dynamically in a create table statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, identity, dynamic-sql

I want to create the tables with identity and no identity by 1 sql file.
I have 1 solution that it is switched 1 of 2 statement by DB name but it is not smart because it needs to fix "2 lines" when table define is changed.
Give me your best practice!!

In "merge" DB

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_result (
    id INT NOT NULL
    ,customer_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,shopping_on DATETIME
    )
```

In "store1","store2",... DB.

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_result (
    id INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,customer_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,shopping_on DATETIME
    )
```

merge JOB

```
INSERT INTO merge.dbo.shopping_result
SELECT *
FROM store1.dbo.shopping_result
WHERE DATE < dateadd(- 1, year, getdate())
```

Comment: I would recommend against it. In your "merge" db, you'll get duplicate values in your `id` column for sure. This is one time that you might want to consider a guid as a surrogate key, or at least have another column in your "merge" db table that will tell you what the origin of the records is ("store1", "store2"..)

Comment: If there is no separate  column in merge DB to identify origin of the record then duplicates will be created..

Comment: As you said, these is not wrong table.
Actually, shopping_result has shop code and set as PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to use dynamic query.

```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @sql ='CREATE TABLE shopping_result (
        id INT '
    IF DB_NAME() LIKE 'store%'
        SET @sql = @sql + 'identity(1, 1) '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'NOT NULL
        ,customer_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        ,shopping_on DATETIME
        )'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```